# Can one can change from Portugal visit visa to long term work visa?

Tags: portugal

Can anyone come to Portugal in visit visa [c visa) and start searching for job? And apply for temporary residency and financial card?

Comment: In general no. Where they exist (Germany) job seeker visas are d-visas since they are based on national law and not the common visa policy.

Comment: Is it illegal? Or I'm asking in general, if one make a legal entry in Portugal by visit visa and search job, and if so any employer can offer him job?